# Regex matching everything except specific words

Tags: sql, regex, regex-negation

I have looked through the other questions asked on excluding regex, but I was unable to find the answer to my question.

I have the SQL statement

```
select --(* vendor(microsoft), product(odbc) guid'12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012' *)-- from TAB
```

With regex, I want to find every single character in that string, except

```
--(* vendor(microsoft), product(odbc)
```

and

```
*)--
```

The vendor and product names (microsoft and odbc) could be anything as well, I still want to exclude it.

I don't care what kind of characters there are, or if the SQL statement is even syntactically correct. The string could look like this, and I still want to find everything, including whitespaces, excluding what I mentioned above:

```
{Jane           Doe?= --(* vendor(micro1macro2?), product(cdb!o) 123$% --(**) *)-- = ?
```

So far, I have this expression:

```
(--\(\* vendor\(.*\), product\(.*?\))|(\*\)--)
```

Which seems to work in finding what I want to exclude https://regex101.com/r/rMbYHz/204. However, I'm unable to negate it.

Comment: Do not negate, just replace with an empty string.

Comment: I do not want to alter the string, I just want to match it.

Comment: You cannot efficiently match parts of a string that do not equal some multicharacter string. It is possible to do with PCRE, but it is not a good idea since the regex may freeze the app.

Comment: With PCRE you would use  eg [`(*SKIP)(*F)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) and match the remaining single characters or use a neg. lookahead at each character for the remaining parts [like your updated demo](https://regex101.com/r/rMbYHz/205) (both are not efficient as Wiktor mentions).

Answer (score 0):

Does `replace()` do what you want?

```
select replace(replace(t.col, '--(* vendor(microsoft), product(odbc)', ''
                      ), '*)--', ''
              )
```